# How to convert "A01" to "A1" using R?

Tags: r

How to convert "A01" to "A1" using R?

As the first step I tried to get the middle character in the string  but I couldn't.

```
STR <- "A01"
p <- as.character(substr(STR,2,1))
```

I get the following for p. I am very new to R. Please advice me.

```
[1] ""
```

Comment: What's the general rule you want to follow? Will all your values start with exactly one letter?

Comment: What if string is "A00"?

Comment: I tried that. When it is "A10", then it should not make it "A1".  It has to be "A10". Any help?

Comment: Yes it will be one letter in the beginning of the string like  "A01"..."A12".  I just want to remove the middle 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use lookaround to replace `0` values:

```
sub('(?<![0-9])0*(?=[0-9])', '', STR, perl=TRUE)
[1] "A1"
```

The expression matches all `0` characters that are not preceded by a number, but are followed by a number.

```
sub('(?<![0-9])0*(?=[0-9])', '', 'A0010', perl=TRUE)
[1] "A10"

sub('(?<![0-9])0*(?=[0-9])', '', 'A00', perl=TRUE)
[1] "A0"
```

Comment: Thank you! You made my day.

Answer (score 4):

We can also do this without regex lookarounds

```
sub("([A-Z]+)0*([0-9]+)", "\\1\\2", c("A01", "A0010", "A00"))
#[1] "A1"  "A10" "A0"
```