# str_replace A1-A9 to A01-A09 and so on

Tags: r, regex, dataframe, str-replace

Hi I have a following strings in my data and would like to replace A1-A9 to A01-A09 and B1-B9 to B01-B09 but keep the numbers `>=10`.

```
rep_data=data.frame(Str= c("A1B10", "A2B3", "A11B1", "A5B10"))

    Str
1 A1B10
2  A2B3
3 A11B1
4 A5B10
```

There is a similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42796247/how-to-convert-a01-to-a1-using-r) but my problem is little bit different! and haven't seen similar example in here [str_replace](http://stringr.tidyverse.org/reference/str_replace.html).

Will be very glad if you know the solution.

expected output

```
Str
1 A01B10
2 A02B03
3 A11B01
4 A05B10
```

Comment: Is that an important requirement to use *tidyverse*?

Comment: not necessarily!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this should get you what you want:

```
gsub("(?<![0-9])([0-9])(?![0-9])", "0\\1", rep_data$Str, perl = TRUE)
#[1] "A01B10" "A02B03" "A11B01" "A05B10"
```

It uses PCRE lookahead's/lookbehind's to match a 1 digit number and then pastes a "0" onto it.

Comment: what is the middle ([0-9]) for?

Comment: It matches a digit. The ones around the middle `([0-9])` match non-digits

Answer (score 3):

How about something like this

```
num_pad <- function(x) {
  x <- as.character(x)
  mm <- gregexpr("\\d+|\\D+",x)  
  parts <- regmatches(x, mm)
  pad_number <- function(x) {
    nn<-suppressWarnings(as.numeric(x))
    x[!is.na(nn)] <- sprintf("%02d", nn[!is.na(nn)])
    x
  }
  parts <- lapply(parts, pad_number)
  sapply(parts, paste0, collapse="")
}


num_pad(rep_data$Str)
# [1] "A01B10" "A02B03" "A11B01" "A05B10"
```

Basically we use regular expressions to split the strings up into digit and non-digit groups. We then find those values that look like numbers and use `sprintf()` to zero-pad them to 2 characters. Then we insert the padded values into the vector and paste everything back together.

Answer (score 2):

Not checked thoroughly

```
x = c("A1B10", "A2B3", "A11B1", "A5B10")
sapply(strsplit(x, ""), function(s){
    paste(sapply(split(s, cumsum(s %in% LETTERS)), function(a){
        if(length(a) == 2){
            a[2] = paste0(0, a[2])
        }
        paste(a, collapse = "")
    }), collapse = "")
})
#[1] "A01B10" "A02B03" "A11B01" "A05B10"
```

Answer (score 2):

A solution from `tidyverse` and `stringr`.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)

rep_data2 <- rep_data %>%
  extract(Str, into = c("L1", "N1", "L2", "N2"), regex = "(A)(\\d+)(B)(\\d+)") %>%
  mutate_at(vars(starts_with("N")), funs(str_pad(., width = 2, pad = "0"))) %>%
  unite(Str, everything(), sep = "")
rep_data2
     Str
1 A01B10
2 A02B03
3 A11B01
4 A05B10
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the most concise tidy solution I can come up with:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)

rep_data %>%
  mutate(
    num_1 = str_match(Str, "A([0-9]+)")[, 2],
    num_2 = str_match(Str, "B([0-9]+)")[, 2],
    num_1 = str_pad(num_1, width = 2, side = "left", pad = "0"),
    num_2 = str_pad(num_2, width = 2, side = "left", pad = "0"),
    Str = str_c("A", num_1, "B", num_2)
  ) %>%
  select(- num_1, - num_2)
```

Answer (score 2):

A bit similar to @Mike's answer, but this solution uses one positive lookahead:

```
gsub("(\\D)(?=\\d(\\D|\\b))", "\\10", rep_data$Str, perl = TRUE)
# [1] "A01B10" "A02B03" "A11B01" "A05B10"
```

With `tidyverse`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

rep_data %>%
  mutate(Str = str_replace_all(Str, "(\\D)(?=\\d(\\D|\\b))", "\\10"))

#      Str
# 1 A01B10
# 2 A02B03
# 3 A11B01
# 4 A05B10
```

This regex matches all non-digits that are followed by a digit and either by another non-digit or a word boundary. `\\10` is quite deceiving since it looks like it is replacing the match with the 10th capture group. Instead, it replaces the match with the 1st capture group plus a zero right after.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one option with `gsubfn`

```
library(gsubfn)
gsubfn("(\\d+)", ~sprintf("%02d", as.numeric(x)), as.character(rep_data$Str))
#[1] "A01B10" "A02B03" "A11B01" "A05B10"
```